# Construction of a Cameron-Martin space

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let us consider the following Cameron-Martin space:

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{H}:=\left \{f:[0,t] \to \mathbb{R}^n,\, f(0)=0, \,  f \, \text{absolutely continuous}, \, \int_0^t |\dot{f}(s)|^2ds<\infty \right \},
\end{equation}

where $\dot{f}$ denotes the distributional derivative of the function $f$. In this case the scalar product defined on $\mathcal{H}$ is:

\begin{equation}
\langle f_1,f_2\rangle:= \int_0^t \dot{f_1}(s)\dot{f_2}(s) ds,
\end{equation}

and the quadratic form is:

\begin{equation}
Q(f):= \int_0^t |\dot{f}(s)|^2 ds.
\end{equation}

I would be interested to understand if it is possible to construct a new Cameron-Martin space, where the quadratic form is defined as:

\begin{equation}
Q(\phi):= \int_0^t \Phi(\phi(s))|\dot{\phi}(s)|^2 ds,
\end{equation}

with $\Phi>0$. Something like:

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{H}_{\Phi}:=\left \{\phi:[0,t] \to \mathbb{R}^n, \,  \phi(0)=0, \,\phi \,\text{absolutely continuous}, \, \int_0^t \Phi(\phi(s))|\dot{f}(s)|^2ds<\infty \right \}.
\end{equation}

Comment: Remember that any Hilbert space embeds as the Cameron-Martin space of some Gaussian measure on a larger Hilbert space. Hence, if $Q$ is a quadratic form induced by a Hilbert space norm, it will be true that $\mathcal H_{\Phi}$ will be the CM space of some Gaussian measure, though not necessarily on a space of functions (but generally on a space of distributions).

Comment: But (most importantly), I highly doubt that in most cases, the $Q$ you have defined is actually a [quadratic form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form#Quadratic_spaces) in the first place. You need some to put some conditions on $\Phi$.

Comment: Thank you @Shalop; I'm trying to generalize the Cemeron-Martin space on a manifold and I thought that It was simpler starting with a conformally flat manifold (with $\Phi$ as conformal factor). This is the reason of my question.

Comment: @Shalop Yes. In the 2D case the Laplace-Beltrami operator  $\Delta_g$ is equal to $\Phi^{-1}\Delta$ with $Phi$ conformal factor, which sometimes is known. If I take e.g. the unit sphere minus the north pole, maybe I could use the stereographic projection.

Comment: I think it is possible to construct under certain hypothesis: https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.5082.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. In fact my previous statements did not make much sense anyways, since $C([0,1],M)$ is not even a vector space for a manifold $M$. So I deleted...

Comment: @Shalop Eh, right. The idea was to use the fact that it would be possible to construct a sort of "bridge" between the manifold and the flat space with the conformal factor.

Comment: These notes might be useful to you: http://www.math.ucsd.edu/%7Ebdriver/DRIVER/Preprints/curved.pdf